# change mybb forum topic icons

Tags: php, html, css, mybb

With the code here, it gives random pictures to the subjects, I want to make that picture a single picture, what should I replace this code with?

`<div class="forum-symbol" role="img" aria-label="{$forum['name']}" style="background-image: url('{$forum['v7_modern_asset_url']}/images/forum/{$forum['fid']}.png')">`
what should i replace this code with

Comment: with a line that references the specific image that you want to use, such as:
`style="background-image: url('path/to/my-image.png')"`  If image is located on same server you may use relative path, if hosted somewhere else, use the full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is inside a loop
you need to give the image URL an absolute path
eg.

```
<div class="forum-symbol" role="img" aria-label="{$forum['name']}" style="background-image: url('/folder/image-name.png')">
```

I hope this helps